# Github project setup in Jenkins 2.x

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-github-plugin

I have a Multibranch Pipeline project which configures Jenkins Jobs based on a `Jenkinsfile` per branch. The sourcecode is hosted on a Github Enterprise Server.

When I view the configuration of a branch which is created by the Jenkinsfile, I noticed that there is a option `GitHub project`. This option allows to define the URL of the corresponding GitHub project.

[image: GitHub project details]

I want to define this property via my Jenkinsfile in Pipeline syntax, but I don't know command to use and how.

Relevant parts of my Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
 agent {
  docker {
    image 'plinzen/android:latest'
    label 'android'
  }
 }

 triggers {
    githubPush()
 }

 stages {
    stage('build') {
        steps {
            checkout scm
            sh './gradlew clean assembleDebug'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I define the `GitHub project` properties via my `Jenkinsfile`? I use the Jenkins GitHub Plugin in my project.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new agent node and add this code snippet to do your things. For more info you can refer to [this url](https://gist.github.com/frekele/847c8a5f458d5c84f5688975c8553848) also. For [Additional Info](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-scm-step-plugin/blob/master/README.md). Hope this helps.

```
git(
   url: 'git@github.com<repo_name>.git',
   credentialsId: 'xpc',
   branch: '${branch}'
)
```